# Line breaks in SMTPLIB Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am trying to make a script that sends a email. But how to do line breaks? I tried the following:

Change `msg = MIMEText(msginp)` to `msg=MIMEText(msginp,_subtype='plain',_charset='windows-1255')`

> NOTE: msginp is a input (`msginp = input('Body? ')`)

Does anybody know how to make line breaks? Like the `enter` key on your keyboard?

My code is:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import getpass
smtpserverinp = input('What SMTP server are you using? (Look here for more information. https://sites.google.com/view/smtpserver) ')
usern = input('What is your email adderess? ')
p = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is your password? (You will not see that you are typing because it is a password) ')
subjectss = input('Subject? ')
msginp = input('Body? ')
toaddr = input('To who do you want to send it to? ')
msg = MIMEText(msginp)

msg['Subject'] = subjectss
msg['From'] = usern
msg['To'] = toaddr

s = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserverinp, 587)
s.starttls()
s.login(usern, p)
s.sendmail(usern, toaddr, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's an easy/straight-forward way to do this in the terminal. It's time to start looking at a simple GUI library like [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add a comment to see if this was totally what you want but i'll give it ago.

Your `msginp = input('Body? ')` ends once you press the enter key, for a new line you'd need to enter `\n`. Rather than typing `\n` each time you can make a loop.
Once all the data has been collected you can use the MIMEText as you would before.

Replace your msginp and MIMEText with this (total is the msginp)

```
total = ""
temp = input("Data: ")
total = temp+"\n"
while(temp!=""):
    temp = input("next line: ")
    total = total+temp+"\n"
msg = MIMEText(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Exit when you enter empty line

```
print("Body? ", end="")

lines = []
while True:
    line = input("")
    if not len(line):
        break
    lines.append(line)

print("\n".join(lines))
```